# prestashop 1.7 new module

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I have a problem in prestashop 1.7, when I load the form.tpl in my module I can not do a `setAction`. What I need is that when I continue in the payment I open a new sale with a payment platform and in prestashop in platform carge the validation I leave the code. help please

main file of the prestashop module

```
         public function hookPaymentOptions($params) {

        if (!$this->active) {
            return;
        }

        $this->smarty->assign(
                $this->getPaymentApiVars()
        );

        $apiPayement = new PaymentOption();
        $apiPayement->setModuleName($this->name)
                ->setLogo($this->context->link->getBaseLink().'/modules/hhpayment/views/img/pago.jpg')
//                ->setCallToActionText($this->l(''))                
                //Définition d'un formulaire personnalisé
                ->setForm($this->fetch('module:hhpayment/views/templates/hook/payment_api_form.tpl'))
                ->setAdditionalInformation($this->fetch('module:hhpayment/views/templates/hook/displayPaymentApi.tpl'))
                 ->setAction($this->context->link->getModuleLink($this->name, 'validation', array(), true));


        return [$apiPayement];
    }
```

this is the form.tpl that I charge this without the method but it is by tests

```
<form action="{$payment_url}" target="_blank" >
    <div class="form-group">
        {* choix du mode de carte *}
        {l s='please choose your card type' mod='hhpayment'}
            <div class="radio">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="cb_type" value="mastercard" id="cb_type1" checked="checked" /> Pago internacional
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="radio">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="cb_type" id="cb_type2" value="visa"/> Pago Nacional
                </label>
            </div>            
    </div>
    {* Informations pour l'api *}
    <input type="hidden" name="success_url" value="{$success_url}" />
    <input type="hidden" name="error_url" value="{$error_url}" />
    <input type="hidden" name="id_cart" value="{$id_cart}" />
    <input type="hidden" name="cart_total" value="{$cart_total}" />
    <input type="hidden" name="id_customer" value="{$id_customer}" />
</form>
```

and this is the validation file

```
class hhpaymentvalidationModuleFrontController extends ModuleFrontController
{


    /**
     * Validation du paiement standard
     * Puis redirection vers la page de succès de commande
     */
    public function postProcess()
    {
         $cart = $this->context->cart;

       $this->abrir("http://davivienda.com");


        if ($cart->id_customer == 0 || $cart->id_address_delivery == 0 || $cart->id_address_invoice == 0 || !$this->module->active) {
            Tools::redirect('index.php?controller=order&step=1');
        }

        $customer = new Customer($cart->id_customer);

        if (!Validate::isLoadedObject($customer)) {
            Tools::redirect('index.php?controller=order&step=1');
        }

        $currency = $this->context->currency;
        $total = (float)$cart->getOrderTotal(true, Cart::BOTH);

        //La command passe directement en statut payé
        $this->module->validateOrder((int)$cart->id, Configuration::get('PS_OS_PAYMENT'), $total, $this->module->displayName, null, array(), (int)$currency->id, false, $customer->secure_key);
        Tools::redirect('index.php?controller=order-confirmation&id_cart='.(int)$cart->id.'&id_module='.(int)$this->module->id.'&id_order='.$this->module->currentOrder.'&key='.$customer->secure_key);
    }

    public function abrir($param) 
    {
        echo" <script> window.open(URL,'ventana1,'width=300,height=300,scrollbars=NO')</script> ";


    }

}
```

Comment: This is English SO. Please post in English.

Comment: sorry but I speak very little english

Comment: Then please post your question in https://es.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: I have a problem in prestashop 1.7, when I load the form.tpl in my module I can not do a setAction what I need is that when I continue in the payment I open a new sale with a payment platform and in prestashop in platform carge the validation I leave the code help please 

is what I ask, I hope you understand

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a solution to this problem, I don't know if it is the correct one, but it already works for me:

The postProcess method passes it to the main and the validation.php file passes it to the same folder where the main file is.

Then it is time to modify the validation.php file which was changed to the same directory as main, this file should be as follows.

It should be imported

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/config/config.inc.php';
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/main.php';
```

Then to avoid a kernel error the following code snippet must be implemented

```
global $kernel;
if(!$kernel){
    require_once _PS_ROOT_DIR_.'/app/AppKernel.php';
    $kernel = new \AppKernel('prod', false);
    $kernel->boot();
}
```

After this, it is necessary to implement the logic and receive the parameters by get that the payment screen will return to us after the payment is made, once this data is received, the cart must be recovered and the data sent to the function that was migrated to the main file

```
ob_start();
    $context = Context::getContext();

if (is_null($context->cart)) {
    $context->cart = new Cart($context->cookie->id_cart);
}
if (is_null($context->cart->id_currency)) {
    $context->cart->id_currency = $context->cookie->id_currency;
}

$cart = $context->cart;
$customer = new Customer($cart->id_customer);
$currency = $cart->id_currency;
$total = (float)$cart->getOrderTotal(true, Cart::BOTH);
$object = new filemain();

$order = $object->methodCreateInMain($cart->id, Configuration::get('PS_OS_PAYMENT'), $total, $currency, $customer->secure_key);
```

Basically the previous code in validation.php retrieves the cart data and sends it by parameter to the function that was passed to main, where the order will be validated and created.

It should be noted that the return url after payment must be `ulrCommerce/module/validation.php`

The above worked perfectly for me and is a solution based on various blogs and forums viewed